# What is the best way to filter groups by two lambda conditions and create a new column based on the conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

This is my DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p'],
        'b': [1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    }
)
```

And this the expected output. I want to create column `c`:

```
    a  b    c
0   x  1    first
1   x -1    first
2   x  1    first
3   x  1    first
4   y -1    second
5   y  1    second
6   y  1    second
7   y -1    second
11  p  1    first
12  p  1    first
13  p  1    first
14  p  1    first
```

Groups are defined by column `a`. I want to filter `df` and choose groups that either their first `b` is 1 OR their second `b` is 1.

I did this by this code:

```
df1 = df.groupby('a').filter(lambda x: (x.b.iloc[0] == 1) | (x.b.iloc[1] == 1))
```

And for creating column `c` for `df1`, again groups should be defined by `a` and then if for each group first `b` is 1 then `c` is `first` and if the second `b` is 1 then `c` is `second`.

Note that for group `p`, both first and second `b` is 1, for these groups I want `c` to be `first`.

Maybe the way that I approach the issue is totally wrong.

Comment: Sorry, missed that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generic method that works with any number of positions for the first `1`:

```
d = {0: 'first', 1: 'second'}

s = (df.groupby('a')['b']
       .transform(lambda g: g.reset_index()[g.values==1]
                  .first_valid_index())
       .replace(d)
     )

out = df.assign(c=s).dropna(subset=['c'])
```

Notes:

- if you remove the `replace` step you will get an integer in `c`
- if you use `map` in place of `replace` you can ignore the positions that are not defined as a dictionary key

Output:

```
    a  b       c
0   x  1   first
1   x -1   first
2   x  1   first
3   x  1   first
4   y -1  second
5   y  1  second
6   y  1  second
7   y -1  second
11  p  1   first
12  p  1   first
13  p  1   first
14  p  1   first
```

Example from comments:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p'],
                  'b': [1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]})

d = {0: 'first', 1: 'second'}

s = (df.groupby('a')['b']
       .transform(lambda g: g.reset_index()[g.values==1]
                  .first_valid_index())
       .map(d)
     )

out = df.assign(c=s).dropna(subset=['c'])

    a  b       c
0   x  1   first
1   x -1   first
2   x  1   first
3   x  1   first
4   y -1  second
5   y  1  second
6   y  1  second
7   y -1  second
11  p  1   first
12  p  1   first
13  p  1   first
14  p  1   first
```

You can also only filter the rows with:

```
m1 = df.groupby('a').cumcount().le(1)
m2 = df['b'].eq(1)
out = df.loc[df['a'].isin(df.loc[m1&m2, 'a'])]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Note that I don't want to keep a group if it has a `1` other than first or second row. for example for this `df` I don't want to keep group `z`. `df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p'],
        'b': [1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    }
)`

Comment: @x_Amir_x then use `map` in place of `replace` ;)

Comment: Ah. My bad :) I want to accept your answer. Do you think it is best one? I've got other answers too.

Comment: @x_Amir_x it's up to you, I'm adding another method if you only want to filter

Answer (score 4):

I think transform could also help in this case-

```
df["c"] = df.groupby("a")["b"].transform(lambda x: "first" if x.iloc[0] == 1 else ("second" if x.iloc[1] == 1 else None))
df.dropna()
```

output ->

```
    a   b   c
0   x   1   first
1   x   -1  first
2   x   1   first
3   x   1   first
4   y   -1  second
5   y   1   second
6   y   1   second
7   y   -1  second
11  p   1   first
12  p   1   first
13  p   1   first
14  p   1   first
```

1.09 ms ± 119 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 10 loops each)

If you want to do everything in a single line, -

```
df = df.assign(c=df.groupby("a")["b"].transform(lambda x: "first" if x.iloc[0] == 1 else ("second" if x.iloc[1] == 1 else None))).dropna()
```

But increases the time to -
1.24 ms ± 357 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 10 loops each)

Comment: No explicit filtering required!

Comment: Using lambda functions with `groupby transform` for boolean masking is not recommended when dealing with a large number of groups, as it can significantly slow down the process. Of course this is not an issue with smaller group sizes, such as the example with 4 groups. I also think that easy-to-understand code is a good answer.

Comment: Thanks for adding for more info into my answer. Will keep that in mind!

Answer (score 3):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter, filter only `1` in `b` and mapping by dictionary only first or second `1` in [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), then remove non matched rows by [`Series.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html), add `a` column by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html), remove duplicates and append to original DataFrame in [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
s = df.groupby('a').cumcount()[df['b'].eq(1)].map({0: 'first', 1: 'second'}).dropna()

out = (df.merge(s.to_frame('c').join(df.a).drop_duplicates('a'), how='left')
         .dropna(subset=['c']))
print (out)
    a  b       c
0   x  1   first
1   x -1   first
2   x  1   first
3   x  1   first
4   y -1  second
5   y  1  second
6   y  1  second
7   y -1  second
11  p  1   first
12  p  1   first
13  p  1   first
14  p  1   first
```

Another idea:

```
s = (df.assign(g = df.groupby('a').cumcount())[df['b'].eq(1)]
       .drop_duplicates('a').set_index('a')['g'])

out = df.assign(c = df['a'].map(s.map({0: 'first', 1: 'second'}))).dropna(subset=['c'])
print (out)
    a  b       c
0   x  1   first
1   x -1   first
2   x  1   first
3   x  1   first
4   y -1  second
5   y  1  second
6   y  1  second
7   y -1  second
11  p  1   first
12  p  1   first
13  p  1   first
14  p  1   first
```

Answer (score 2):

**Code**

use groupby `nth`

```
g = df.groupby(['a'])['b']
first = g.nth(0)[lambda x: x.eq(1)].replace(1, 'first')
second = g.nth(1)[lambda x: x.eq(1)].replace(1, 'second')
m = {**second, **first}
df['c'] = df['a'].map(m)
```

df

```
    a   b   c
0   x   1   first
1   x   -1  first
2   x   1   first
3   x   1   first
4   y   -1  second
5   y   1   second
6   y   1   second
7   y   -1  second
8   z   -1  NaN
9   z   -1  NaN
10  z   -1  NaN
11  p   1   first
12  p   1   first
13  p   1   first
14  p   1   first
```

---

filter:

```
out = df[df['c'].notna()]
```

Answer (score 2):

While pandas has `idxmax()`, numpy has `argmax()` which instead of giving the index label like `idxmax()`, it will give the position.

```
(df.assign(
    c = df['b'].where(df['b'].eq(1))
    .groupby(df['a'])
    .transform(lambda x: x.argmax())
    .map(dict(enumerate(['first','second'])))
    )
    .dropna(subset = 'c'))
```

Output:

```
    a  b       c
0   x  1   first
1   x -1   first
2   x  1   first
3   x  1   first
4   y -1  second
5   y  1  second
6   y  1  second
7   y -1  second
11  p  1   first
12  p  1   first
13  p  1   first
14  p  1   first
```